# How can you give yourself a block if you break that block using commands?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to figure out how to get blocks by breaking them using commands. Say I'm breaking a diamond ore block and tile drops are turned off so other players can't steal your blocks.

Is there a command to give me that diamond ore block when I break it?

Answer (score 2):

You could turn on `gamerule doTileDrops` whenever the player is near that block.

---

You could use `/loot` to give yourself the block, but that only works before it is mined:

```
loot give @s mine <coordinates>
```

---

You could just simply `/give` the block to the player, if you already know what it is.

---

You could `/kill` the drop whenever a different player is nearby.

---

You could `/clear` the item out of other players' inventories.

---

You could use spawn protection on a server and `/op` yourself so that you can still place and mine inside the spawn protection area.

---

You could put other players into Adventure mode when they are nearby.

Answer (score 2):

## Yes

If you have a list of ores/other blocks you want this to work on use these 4 commands:

> `/scoreboard objectives add DiamondOre minecraft.mined:minecraft.diamond_ore`

Then have a repeating command block with:

> `execute if score DiamondOre matches 1 run scoreboard players remove (YourNameHereI) DiamondOre 1`

Then place a chain command block set to conditional with the line:

> `give (YourNameHere) diamond`

Then you need to turn of tile drops using:

> `/gamerule doTileDrops false`

Comment: Why doesn't it work in Creative Mode?

Comment: In creative, I suspect that breaking blocks does not count as mining the block